# Rerouting react app just displays content on same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

So I am making a react web app and the main page has a search bar function. I want the user to enter a search result and when they click on 'search' they should be redirected to a new page (component) that displays details about their specific search.

However currently when the user clicks search the content that is supposed to be on a new page is just displayed underneath the contents of the main page.

```
Here is the code for my App.js file: 
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import SearchBar from './ui-components/SearchBarNew';
import PlanDisplay from './ui-components/planDisplay';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import SearchResultsPage from './SearchResultsPage';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <SearchBar />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/search-results/:term" element={<SearchResultsPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
    </Router>
    
  );
}


export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

And here is the code for the SearchBar component that is supposed to redirect the user to a component called SearchResultsPage.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';



const listCourseNames = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListCourseNames {
    listCourseInfos(limit: 1000) {
      items {
        course_name
      }
    }
  }
`;

const SearchBar = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  const [courseNames, setCourseNames] = useState([]);
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);
  const [selectedSuggestion, setSelectedSuggestion] = useState(null);

  // Load course names from API on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCourseNames = async () => {
      try {
        const apiKey = '****************';
        const { data: { listCourseInfos: { items: courseInfoItems } } } = await API.graphql({
          query: listCourseNames,
          variables: {
            limit: 1000,
          },
          headers: {
            'x-api-key': apiKey,
          },
        });
        const courseNames = courseInfoItems.map((item) => item.course_name);
        setCourseNames(courseNames);
        console.log(`Retrieved ${courseNames.length} course names from API`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching course names:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchCourseNames();
  }, []);

  const handleInputChange = useCallback((event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setSearchText(value);
    const newSuggestions = courseNames.filter(name => name.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase())).slice(0, 5);
    setSuggestions(newSuggestions);
    setSelectedSuggestion(null);
  }, [courseNames]);

  const handleSuggestionClick = useCallback((suggestion) => {
    setSearchText(suggestion);
    setSelectedSuggestion(null);
  }, []);

 

  const handleSubmit = useCallback((event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    navigate(`/search-results/${encodeURIComponent(searchText)}`);
  }, [navigate, searchText]);
  
  

  return (
    <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={searchText} onChange={handleInputChange} />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      {suggestions.length > 0 && (
        <ul style={{ 
          position: 'absolute', 
          top: '100%', 
          left: 0, 
          width: '100%',
          background: 'black', 
          boxShadow: '0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)', 
          listStyleType: 'none', 
          zIndex: 1 }}>
          {suggestions.map((name) => (
            <li 
              key={name} 
              style={{ 
                padding: '5px', 
                cursor: 'pointer',
                fontSize: '14px' 

              }} 
              onClick={() => handleSuggestionClick(name)}>
              {name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "main page" I'm assuming everything the `App` component is rendering *other than* the routes is what you are calling the "main page". This content is unconditionally rendered and the routed content is rendered below it. If you want separate routes to delineate a "main" page from a "search result" page then you'll want to move the UI content to a route as well.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={(
              <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <SearchBar />
                <p>
                  Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
                </p>
                <a
                  className="App-link"
                  href="https://reactjs.org"
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                  Learn React
                </a>
              </header>
            )}
          />
          <Route path="/search-results/:term" element={<SearchResultsPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In it's current state, your code consists of an App component.  This component has a search bar at the top, and then a space underneath that will be filled with content depending on your current route.  If I were you, I would wrap this chunk of code

```
     <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <SearchBar />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
```

into a `<Header>` component.  Then, your main page will be

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/search-results/:term" element={<SearchResultsPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
    
  );
}
```

Then, based on your question, I think you will want to make a change something like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Header/>} />
          <Route path="/search-results/:term" element={<SearchResultsPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Now, your app is just going to contain a single div, and then this div will contain EITHER a `<Header>` element, OR a `<SearchResultsPage>` element, depending on your current URL/path.